# Firebird sample database(s) recomendation for learning database design and administration

Tags: database, firebird, firebird2.5

My **Firebird** installation comes with the EMPLOYEE.fdb database to get you started. I am interested in example firebird database(s) that I can use as examples of good database design and practice admnistrative tasks with. (I have firebird 2.5 installation on a Windows 7 machine.)

Answer (score 1):

I think [IBExpert](http://www.ibexpert.com) have demo DB

You can also check [sakila](http://www.firebirdnews.org/?p=6241) database